# Как переопределять стили в media запросах?

Tags: css, scss, media-queries, css-selectors

Почему оригинальные стили не переопределяются в `@media`? Вес селекторов одинаковый `.home .breadcrumbs`, `id` в селекторах нет. Как заставить `@media` переопределять нижеследующие стили?

[image: Пример №2]

**КОД style (scss)**

```
$breadcrumbs_margin: 40px;
.home {
   .breadcrumbs {
      font-size: 100%;
      padding: 0;
      height: 100%;
      ul {
         padding: 0;
         margin: 0;
      }
      li {
         margin-left: $breadcrumbs_margin/2;
         margin-right: $breadcrumbs_margin/2;
         a {
            font-weight: normal;
            font-size: 115%;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**КОД mobile (scss)**

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {
    .home {
        .breadcrumbs {
        font-size: 70%;
            li {
                margin-left: 1.1vw;
                margin-right: 1.1vw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**КОД index (Jade)**

```
link(rel="stylesheet", type="text/css", href="css/style.css")
link(rel="stylesheet", type="text/css", href="css/mobile.css")
```

Дествительно, сейчас решил попробовать `min-width`, т.к. вопрос создавался довольно таки давно.

Comment: Оригинальные стили сначала должны идти, потом @media. В такой последовательности все переопределяется при активации того или иного @media. И про `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />` не забываем.

Comment: Так и есть, сначала оригинальные стили, затем `@media (max-width: 1000px)`, `@media (max-width: 880px)` и так далее. `!important` в оригиналах нет

Comment: Мне кажется, что ваш запрос не работает, т.к. вложенность классов отличается от оригинала:
в оригинале - `#news .news_item-title`
в запросе - `#news .news_item .news_item-title`
Укажите в запросе точно такой же каскад как в оригинале

Comment: Код покажите? Может там еще что то есть, что переопределяет стили. Не понятно, что вы все таки используете `max-width` или `min-width`. Может последовательной подключения файлов mobile.scss и style.scss не правильная.

Comment: @greybutton достаточно сильно изменил вопрос

Comment: 1) Не могу соотнести картинку с кодом: 1.1) на картинке от ширины в `320px` начинается `font-size: 200%;`, а в коде -  `font-size: 70%;`; 1.2) на картинке медиа-запрос `min-width 1200px`, которого в коде нет. 2) Похоже, картинка сделана, когда ширина окна была меньше `1200px`.

Comment: Поменяйте местами подключение файлов `style.css` и `mobile.css`.  
В `style.css` стили для всех экранов, в `mobile.css` для экранов шириной от 320px и выше, можно сказать, что тоже для всех и т.к. `mobile.css` подключен ниже `style.css`, `mobile.css` перебивает стили `style.css`.
    
Правильный вариант подключения

    link(rel="stylesheet", type="text/css", href="css/mobile.css") 
    link(rel="stylesheet", type="text/css", href="css/style.css")

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы хотите, чтобы заработало нижеследующее:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) .home .breadcrumbs {
  font-size: 100%;
}
```

Есть два варианта решений:

1. Определить `max-width` у @media для мобилок;
2. Дать `!important` свойству DOM.

**Первый вариант решения:**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 1199px) .home .breadcrumbs {
      font-size: 200%;
    }

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) .home .breadcrumbs {
      font-size: 100%;
    }
```

**Второй вариант решения:**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) .home .breadcrumbs {
      font-size: 200%;
    }

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) .home .breadcrumbs {
      font-size: 100% !important;
    }
```

В противном случае у Вас одно правило накладывается на другое, так как, начиная с ширины 1200px, есть два случая:

```
font-size: 200%;
font-size: 100%;
```

В итоге работать будет работать только то, что было определенно раннее:

```
font-size: 200%;
```

**P.S.** Приветствую земляка.

Answer (score 0):

Из того, что я вижу на вашем скрине, всё переопределяется вполне логично. У вас есть первый файл **style.css** с кодом для всех разрешений, следом подключается второй файл **mobile.css** с кодом медиа-выражения `@media screen and (min-width: 320px)`, который переопределит ваш предыдущий CSS-код в диапазоне разрешений экрана *от 320 пикселей*. То есть, когда вы включаете эмулятор мобильного или заходите с мобильного телефона, где разрешение 320 пикселей, то код из файла **style.css** кодом из файла **mobile.css** переопределен не будет.

Чтобы переопределить CSS-код для девайсов 320 пикселей и меньше, необходимо медиа-выражение `@media screen and (max-width: 320px) { ... }`. Т. е. в медиа-выражении вы указываете границы применения вашего кода, где `min-width` является начальной точкой применений кода, а `max-width` — конечной. Например, чтобы сделать код для девайсов от 320 пикселей до 600 пикселей, вам понадобится медиа-выражение `@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 600px)`.